# rightward and leftward arrows between two items

Tags: tikz-pgf

Say, I want to draw a picture showing the export and import from USA to Canada, the code I tried was:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0,0){USA};
\node (b) at (1,0){Canada}; 
\draw [->] (a)--node[above]{export}(b); 
\draw [->](b)--node[below]{import}(a);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I know this is absolutely wrong cause it only generates one arrow with two heads. How could I modify this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. You can use the `to` operator and its `bend left` or `bend right` options. This operators accepts other options such as `looseness` to control the curvature, `in` and `out` to control the start and end angles, see for instance [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526868/73317). For more information on the available options, you can look for `/tikz/curve to` in the [Ti*k*Z & PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (page 838 in version 3.1.5b of the manual).

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\node (a) at (0,0) {USA};
\node (b) at (1,0) {Canada};
\draw[->] (a) to[bend left=20] node[above] {export} (b);
\draw[->] (b) to[bend left=20] node[below] {import} (a);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you omit `[bend left=20]` for an arrow, or use `[bend left=0]` or `[bend right=0]`, Ti*k*Z will draw a straight line (a segment).

If you want to shift such arrows, I think you need to choose an anchor on each of the nodes `a` and `b`, so that the points to shift are well-known. For instance, if I choose anchors `a.30` (30 is a polar angle in degrees) and `b.150` (150 = 180 - 30 for symmetry), shift these points upwards by `0.1cm` and increase the curvature of the upper arrow, we get:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\node (a) at (0,0) {USA};
\node (b) at (1,0) {Canada};
\draw[->] ([yshift=0.1cm]a.30) to[bend left=40] node[above] {export}
          ([yshift=0.1cm]b.150);
\draw[->] (b) to[bend left=20] node[below] {import} (a);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A negative value for `yshift` would shift downwards, of course.

Another possibility for drawing the curved arrows would be to use the `..` operator, but it may be a bit more difficult, as you need to provide appropriate control points.

Comment: Thank you very much! You have completely solved my problem! BTW, what will I do if I just draw two straight arrows without any curvature(or maybe zero curvature is an alternative)? is there any option to move a given arrow upward or downward for a given distance? Thanks

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I really appreciate you for giving me a complete and patient instruction! I learned a lot! also, I am sorry for wasting your time. Thanks!

Comment: It's okay, you didn't *force* me to answer. :-) Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

A small variation og @frougon answer. With using packages `arrows.meta`, `positioning` and `quotes` the MWE for you diagram can be:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 22mm,
every edge/.style = {draw, -Straight Barb, bend left=15},
                        ]
\node (a)               {USA};
\node (b) [right=of a]  {Canada};
\draw   (a) edge["export"] (b)
        (b) edge["import"] (a);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 22mm,
    LA/.style = {draw, -Straight Barb, transform canvas={yshift=#1}},
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\small, inner sep=1pt}
                        ]
\node (a)               {USA};
\node (b) [right=of a]  {Canada};
\draw   (a) edge[LA=+2pt,"export"] (b)
        (b) edge[LA=-2pt,"import"] (a);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Including usetikzlibrary with such packages is a very good idea to shift an arrow using relative distance. I have tried the usetikzlibrary with calc package which is hard to manipulate cause horizontal distance is also required to avoid overlapping. It's very kind of you!